# Scraping Google Search Results

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to Scrape Google Results using `beautifulsoup`.  The results I get back are not what is displayed on the screen.  What is needed to convert the results to the real text I see on the screen?

I have only tried to print out the soup and it looks nothing like the Results on the screen.

```py
search_item = 'site:Facebook.com Dentist gmail.com'
url="https://www.google.com/search?q=" + search_item
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
print(soup)
```

I want to be able to parse out the Title, URL, Phone Number, and Email from the Google Results:

```
4M Dentistry - About | Facebook - Brno
https://www.facebook.com/dentist.brno/about/
 Rating: 5 - ‎25 votes
725 857 346 E-mail dentistry.b@gmail.com. Dental Surgery ensures the complete dental care for children and adults. Restorative and aesthetic dentistry, prosthetics ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Google is known to give you different results if the *User-Agent* is missing in the request.

You can add it like this

```
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36'
}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Documentation: *[Custom Headers](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers)*

Comment: Thanks!  I appreciate your time and effort!

Comment: The custom headers did work.  I still got the same results.  Thanks agian!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I had to convert results to UTF8  here si the code I used.  Works great!

```
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
newvar = soup.decode("utf8")
print("doublej = ", newvar)
```

Answer (score 0):

This script scrapes Title, Url, Email, Rating, Votes, and Snippet.

The trickiest part is to scrape emails.
To scrape email address from Google Search Results you need to parse `snippet` (summary) and then use `regex` to find a pattern in this `snippet` (summary) to grab `@gmail` addresses.

---

To grab emails we can do this (*it worked for me*):

- `match_email = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', snippet)` - will find email address.
- `email = '\n'.join(match_email)` - will convert them from `list` to a `string` and print them on a new line (`\n`)

---

Code and example in [online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Search-Scrape-Title-Email-Rating-Votes):

```py
import requests, lxml, re, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {'q': 'site:Facebook.com Dentist gmail.com'}

html = requests.get(f'https://www.google.com/search?q=',
                    headers=headers,
                    params=params).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

data = []

for container in soup.findAll('div', class_='tF2Cxc'):
    title = container.select_one('.DKV0Md').text
    link = container.find('a')['href']

    try:
        rating = container.select_one('g-review-stars+ span').text
    except:
        rating = None

    try:
        votes = container.select_one('span:nth-child(3)').text
    except:
        votes = None

    try:
        price_range = container.select_one('#rso span~ span+ span').text
    except:
        price_range = None

    snippet = container.select_one('.lyLwlc span').text
    
    match_email = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', snippet)
    email = '\n'.join(match_email)

    data.append({
        'Title': title,
        'Link': link,
        'Email': email,
        'Rating': rating,
        'Votes': votes,
        'Price_range': price_range,
    })

print(json.dumps(data, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Part of the JSON output:

```json
[
  {
    "Title": "LI Dental Group, LLP - Dentist & Dental Office - 452 Photos ...",
    "Link": "https://www.facebook.com/lidentalgroup/about/",
    "Email": "nydental@gmail.com",
    "Rating": "Rating: 2.3",
    "Votes": "3 votes"
  },
  {
    "Title": "Perfect Smiles Dental Studio - General Dentist - Santa Clarita ...",
    "Link": "https://www.facebook.com/dentistcanyoncountry/about/",
    "Email": "perfecsmilesad@gmail.com",
    "Rating": null,
    "Votes": null
  },
  {
    "Title": "Forest Dental Center - General Dentist - Lynchburg, Virginia ...",
    "Link": "https://www.facebook.com/ForestDentalCenter/about/",
    "Email": "forestdentalch@gmail.com",
    "Rating": "Rating: 4.8",
    "Votes": "203 votes"
  }
]
```

Alternatively, you can use [Google Search Engine Results API](https://serpapi.com/search-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free trial of 5,000 searches. A completely free trial is currently under development.

Code to integrate using SerpApi:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import os, json, re 

params = {
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "site:Facebook.com Dentist gmail.com",
  "api_key": os.getenv('API_KEY')
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

data = []

for result in results['organic_results']:
  title = result['title']
  link = result['link']
  snippet = result['snippet']
  match_email = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', snippet)
  email = '\n'.join(match_email)
  try:
    rating = result['rich_snippet']['top']['detected_extensions']['rating']
  except:
    rating = None
  try:
    votes = result['rich_snippet']['top']['detected_extensions']['votes']
  except:
    votes = None
  try:
    price_range = result['rich_snippet']['top']['extensions'][2]
  except:
    price_range = None

  data.append({
    'title':title,
    'link':link,
    'email':email,
    'rating':rating,
    'votes':votes,
    'price_range':price_range,
  })

print(json.dumps(data, indent = 2, ensure_ascii = False))
```

Part of the JSON output:

```json
[
  {
    "title": "LI Dental Group, LLP - Dentist & Dental Office - 452 Photos ...",
    "link": "https://www.facebook.com/lidentalgroup/about/",
    "email": "nydental@gmail.com",
    "rating": 2.3,
    "votes": 3,
    "price_range": "‎Price range: $$"
  },
  {
    "title": "Perfect Smiles Dental Studio - General Dentist - Santa Clarita ...",
    "link": "https://www.facebook.com/dentistcanyoncountry/about/",
    "email": "perfecsmilesad@gmail.com",
    "rating": null,
    "votes": null,
    "price_range": null
  }
]
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.